# How to clean the /boot directory on LINUX Mint?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint

After yesterday's update of Linux Mint Mate (64bit), I started to receive a warning about "Full disk space". I have 400 MB for the `/boot` partition on my hard disk.

This is the screen-shot of the `/boot` files.

[image: screenshot1]

This is the screen-shot of the update-log.

[image: acreenshot2]

The question is: **How can I clean the `/boot`?**  What files are safe to delete?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: You have 4 bootable installations (4.4.0-31, -34, -36 and -38). You are unlikely ever to need more than one previous boot, so uninstall and completely remove all the -31 and -34 files (I find `synaptic` easiest), and you will halve the size of `/boot`.

Comment: Whenever possible, please post text, not screenshots. Text is searchable and scrollable, and people who use screen readers are able to read it and help you. You can use the `ls` command to list the contents of a directory, and `cat` or `less` to show the contents of a file, in this case, `/var/log/apt/history.log` may be helpful. Copy text by selecting it in the terminal, and middle-click to insert it into a post. Before and after, put three inverted commas (or 'backticks') i.e. \`\`\` on lines by themselves, so it gets formatted correctly in your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I received this response from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40526745/5848185) before they flag my question...

Check the current kernel version with uname -r and make sur that the current kernel work without any problem to keep it.

```
From the terminal:
```

List the installed kernel :

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
```

Remove the old kernels through the following command:

```
apt-get purge linux-image-x...
apt-get purge linux-headers-x...
```

**using the synaptic package manager**

Open Synaptic and mark the old kernel versions for removal then apply changes

**Update Manager**

from the Update Manager view the Linux kernels , click the 'Remove' button for the kernels that you want to remove

**Purge-old-kernels**

You can install the purge-old-kernels cli tool through:

```
sudo apt-get install bikeshed
```

If you want to purge the old kernel except for the latest 2 kernels, run the following command:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep 2
```

Finally run

```
sudo update-grub 
sudo update-grub2
```

Answer (score 5):

Old kernels are the most often reason why `/boot` has low amount of space.

Since 19.2 Linux Mint has a GUI to remove old kernels manually and to set up automatic maintenance.

## To remove manually

In the Update Manager (`mintupdate`) select "View" -> "Linux Kernels" to open kernel management window. Press "Remove kernels" button, select unneeded kernels and press "Apply".

I advise leaving at least one old kernel just in case.

[image]

## To set up automatic removal

In the Update Manager (`mintupdate`) select "Edit" -> "Preferences", switch to "Automation" tab. Enable "Automatic maintenance".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Get the current of list of installed kernel packages:

> dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2 }' | grep -e [0-9]

View current kernel version:

> uname -r

Take away the old versions of packages that are older than the current kernel by specifying them separated by a space in command:

> sudo apt-get purge

Comment: I got this:linux-base
linux-firmware
linux-headers-4.4.0-21
linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-31
linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-34
linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-36
linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-38
linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-42
linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-43
linux-headers-4.4.0-43-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-45
linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-47
linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic
...

Comment: Wow... You have too many kernels! Remove all packages that has version and it different from `uname -r` result

Comment: Seems like a normal number of kernels, to me, for a healthy machine that doesn't get rebooted often. I love Mint, but I think it's a failing that it doesn't clean these up by itself.